# How to show view on the current page?

Tags: redirect, routes, ofbiz

I am making use of the `org.ofbiz.webtools.GenericWebEvent` service which is invoking the `updateGeneric` method, instead of having multiple routes for all the different forms, I've created one which manages them all using the following code:

**controller.xml**

```
<request-map uri="process">
    <security https="true" auth="true"/>
    <event type="java" path="org.ofbiz.webtools.GenericWebEvent" invoke="updateGeneric"/>
    <response name="success" type="view" value="home"/>
    <response name="error" type="view" value="CURRENT_PAGE_HERE"/>
</request-map>
```

As you can see in the `error` part, the value shown is `CURRENT_PAGE_HERE`, I'd like the route to show whatever page that is being displayed, for example error occurs on login, re-show login with the notice, error occurs on register, re-show register etc.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The GenericWebEvent#updateGeneric method is a functionality used to update GenericValues and is used in the Webtools to edit/update the data.

The class name GenericWebEvent might be a bit misleading here but if you have a look at the implementation it should be clear that it does not generically handle different web events like you want to do.